# Backup of Azure Repos

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I got a requirement to backup Azure Devops Repos to either Azure Blob or Sharepoint Libraries.
I have created a pipeline using [this](https://charbelnemnom.com/how-to-backup-azure-devops-git-repositories/) approach. But my pipeline fails in the first step itself while copying Repo to Working Directory. Error : **400 error : "fatal: unable to access {Repo Name}"**

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
   script: 'git clone --mirror https://{Your PAT}@dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_git/{RepoName}'
```

The PAT I am using is having full access. I also tried Powershell approach but it also gives same error.
Powershell :

```
$MyPat = 'Access Token'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $B64Pat" clone "https://dev.azure.com/<Org>/<Project>/_git/<Repo>"
```

Any help or guidance regarding this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have whitespaces in your `OrgName` or `ProjectName`? If you do, try replacing those with `%20` and try again.

Comment: Yes I have spaces but I gave the whole Repo Url in quotes, so I thought it might work. I will try now and see with '%20'

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zainul replied, space in the url should be replaced by '*%20*' if there are whitespaces in `OrgName` or `ProjectName`.